# Responsive screen size has play when on small screen

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, layout

all.

I have read many threads, I however, am at an impass.

I have built a website with React, which I hope it is OK to link.

[https:ishaqamin.dev](https://ishaqamin.dev)

When I am on a mobile device, the screen can be moved around and shows white around the sides.

I have tried;

1. height: 100%
2. height:100vh
3. minHeight:100vh

It does not seem to stop it.

I would prefer, on mobile, if the screen was fixed and did not move around.

Home screen settings:

```
    <div style={{display:'flex',flexDirection:'column' ,alignItems:'center', width:'100%', minHeight:'100vh',backgroundColor:'black', padding:20}}>
        <Paper elevation={3} style={{display:'flex',flexDirection:'column', height:'95%', width:'90%', backgroundColor:'black',padding:10}}>
```

Any ideas?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are giving padding 20px and width: 100% just made padding 0 check now

[image: img]

Comment: Thanks, man. That helped. I am still working around with web dev. Mainly did mobile.

Answer (score 0):

use css reset codes:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```